# Powershell syntax, how to use variable in expression to pin folder to quick access

Tags: powershell, variables, syntax, expression

TLDR: Batch file works, creates new dir, calls power shell script. Need help with powershell syntax to pin the new folder to Quick Access using a variable for the folder path.

The batch file prompts for input (street address) then copies a nested directory template using robocopy /E, names the new dir as the street address, and opens the new dir.

I am outputting %address% to address.txt (overwritten each time the batch runs) so I can pass the string (new folder name) to powershell with Get-Content.

Here's the bat:

```
    @echo off
    TITLE Create Digital Workfile
    set fileBase=MAC-22-
    
    ::GET INPUT
    set /p address= "Enter Subject Address: "
    echo.
    set /p effDate= "Enter Inspection Date MMDD: "
    set fileNum=%fileBase%%effDate%
    set pathX=C:\Users\M\Documents\2022\%address%
    echo.
    echo Workfile: %address% ... File#: %fileNum% 
    echo.
    pause
    
    ::MAKE DIR
    robocopy C:\Users\M\Documents\2022\MWF "C:\Users\M\Documents\2022\%address%" /E /COPY:DASO /NDL /NFL /R:5 /W:5

    echo Workfile: %address% ... for File#: %fileNum% ... was created successfully!
    echo.
    echo %address% > %cd%\address.txt

    ::OPEN DIR
    explorer "%pathX%"
    
    ::Confirm data export
    notepad.exe %cd%\address.txt
    
    ::Open Chrome to Lake County Prop Appraiser search page
    ::start https://lakecopropappr.com/property-search.aspx
    
    pause

    ::open PS to pin DIR to quick access
    powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File pin2QuickAccess.ps1
    
    ::END
    endlocal
    exit
```

The batch calls the powershell script to pin the new folder to the quick access menu.
*This works but only if I use an absolute path to an existing folder.

**The PS script does not work when trying to use powershell variables in the expression, no matter how I try to format.

With PS I can get the "address" string (new folder name) from address.txt and "mypath" (full path to new folder) and assign to PS variables. I can also output these vars to new text files "confirm 1.txt" and confirm2.txt" to confirm the data is being piped from batch file to text file to powershell with each execution.

However, when I try to use $mypath in the expression as the path to the new folder, I keep getting similar errors:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:13 char:1
+ $qa.NameSpace($mypath).Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome");
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

I have tried many syntax variations but can not figure this out...

```
    $address1 = Get-Content -First 1 'C:\Users\M\Documents\2022\address.txt'
    
    $mypath = "C:\Users\M\Documents\2022\$address1"
    
    # confirm working
    Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Users\M\Documents\2022\confirm1.txt' -InputObject $address1
    Out-File -FilePath 'C:\Users\M\Documents\2022\confirm2.txt' -InputObject $mypath
    
    #Pin to QA - THIS WORKS WITH ABSOLUTE PATH to existing folder
    $qa = New-Object -ComObject shell.application; 
    $qa.NameSpace("C:\Users\M\Documents\2022\123 Test St Anytown").Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome");
    
    #**HOW TO USE VARIABLE $mypath IN THIS EXPRESSION???**
    $qa = New-Object -ComObject shell.application;
    $qa.NameSpace($mypath).Self.InvokeVerb("pintohome");
```

All files, bat+ PS & logs, and folders (src and dest) are in the same dir: C:\Users\M\Documents\2022\

Thanks in advance.

edit: added the bat file to post.

Comment: Instead of describing verbosely what the batch file does, show the batch file.

Comment: Also, have you *really looked* at what `$address1` (and subsequently `$mypath`) contains? You're assuming that it's a single string, not an array, no linebreaks, no stray spaces at the end. Have you actually double-checked?

Comment: Also check if `$mypath` contains null characters (i.e. using: `Format-Hex -InputObject $mypath`)

Comment: Testing if a path is valid should, of course, be done using: `Test-Path -Path $mypath`   (see: [Test-Path](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-5.1))

Comment: Try to do `Get-Content -First 1` to make sure you are reading only a single line instead of trailing newlines and stuff.

Comment: Its working now. I was looking at the var strings in console and notepad but was not checking with Format-Hex or Test Path. After these checks and some edits it got sorted. Thanks for the tips. Using both Notepad++ and PowerShell ISE helped this learning process as well. Why is automating mundane redundant tasks so rewarding, even if it wastes a bunch of time??